# Creating a central bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am trying to create a central bibliography (`.bib` file) in a directory outside of my LaTeX project. I want to do this so I don't have to have different `.bib`'s for each paper I write. Currently in each `.tex` file I write:

```
\bibliography{central-bibliography}
```

at the end where I want to put it. My `.bib` file is called `central-bibliography.bib`.
The `.bib` file is in the same directory as the `.tex` file.

If I put the `.bib` file in an arbitrarily located directory, how would I reference it in the `.tex` file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can reference `central-bibliography.bib` at an absolute or relative (preferred) location from within the `\bibliography` command:

```
\bibliography{../references/central-bibliography}
```

Note the use of `/` and not `\`. Although it is not always required, using `/` (forward slash) works across most (all?) operating systems.

If you want to modify this from a location at the start of your document, you could also define a command to store the relative location:

```
\documentclass{<class>}
\newcommand{\myreferences}{../references/central-bibliography}
%...
\begin{document}
%...
\bibliography{\myreferences}
%...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 33):

The easiest way to do this is to place your `.bib` file where TeX can find it, which is conveniently done using your local TeX tree. Some of the basics for finding the right location are discussed in [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files), which focusses on `.sty` files. On my TeX Live installations, I use the locations:

- Windows `C:\Users\<user name>\texmf\bibtex\bib\local`
- Mac OS X `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/local`
- Linux `~/texmf/bibtex/bib/local`

With a recent TeX Live, you can simply place your `.bib` file in the appropriate place and it will be found, so you can use

```
\bibliography{myfile}
```

with no path at all. With an older TeX Live you may need to run `texhash` first. MiKTeX also allows the same local installation procedure.

The only minor issue with placing a `.bib` file in your local texmf tree is that it's not so convenient for editing as if it were in the Documents folder. I get around this by using a link, so I actually have my `.bib` file on my Mac in `~/Documents/Literature` and link from there to `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/local` using the Unix `ln` command. On Windows 7 you can do a similar thing using the `mklink` (you need to have Admin rights to do this).

---

An alternative approach is to use the `BIBINPUTS` environmental variable to set a path to be searched for `.bib` files, again allowing you use the file name directly with no path. Setting environmental variables depends on the operating system you are using.

Comment: TeX Live is slightly pickier about placement of these files. ".bib" files go in 
~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib 
or subfolders of this directory, and ".bst" files go in 
~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst 
or subfolders of this directory.

Comment: If you are using `bib2gls` with the `glossaries-extra` package you should also use these locations.

Comment: adding the central path as a BIBINOUTS environment variable worked though it seems that the citation suggestions when I begin with ```\cite{```` don't auto populate.

Comment: Do we make a hard link or a soft link to the bib file in another folder?

Answer (score 3):

Simply, put your bibfile in any place in your laptop. For example in the Drive "D" in the folder Ph.D.

Now, suppose your bibfile`s name is centralbibfile.bib
All what you need to do is to tell the program where is your bibfile and what is its name as follows:
[image]

\bibliography{D:/Ph.D/centralbibfile}

Comment: This is already covered in the existing answer(s).

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution finally and it is work 100%. This is help you to creating central bibliography for all documents and also mendeley sync your library automaticly.

First you have to locate your main MikTex file directory and "base" file. Mine is

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bib\base`

If you use windows 7 or later you definitelly set mendeley for working admin at all time. 
Right click on mendeley shortcut or .exe and select properties. In the Properties box, select the Compatibility tab and then check “Run this program as an administrator”. It is done.

Second you have to set mendeley for creating "library.bib" in this location. It is simple open mendeley and go

```
tools > options > bibtex
```

click browse and set it for "base" file location.

Refresh your library or close and open mendeley. Make sure library.bib file is created in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bib\base`

Last step go "MikTex settings(admin)"

Click "Refresh FNBD" and after click "Update Formats" button.

If you did everthing right it is definitelly work correctly.