# relative paths for bibtex in lyx

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx, paths

I insert a bibliography into my LyX document through `insert > list/TOC > bibtex bibliography`. I find my file and everything works out. However, the path it uses is absolute as opposed to relative so when I open things up on another machine the bibliography is not found. How do I specify a relative path for my bibtex file in LyX?

Comment: I believe the recommended solution is to not use any path at all. Put the .bib file where your TeX distribution can find it. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38287/creating-a-central-bibliography/38297#38297).

Comment: yeh i did that as a work around but it's sort of annoying since i have several files working off the same cites

Answer (score 4):

I have a German version of LyX, so no guarantee for the correct translation of Buttons etc., but:

1. click on the `bibtex created reference database`
2. the window where you can define the database opens: click on `Add...`
3. instead of choosing something from the list or clicking on `Browse...` just type the relative path to the textfield in between. Syntax which was working on my Windows PC: `../Quellen/Literaturdatenbank`, where `Literaturdatenbank` is the BibTeX-File (`*.bib`)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.