# Making subdirectories for each .tex document (with AUX files) but still access .bib file at higher directory

Tags: biblatex, auxiliary-files, directory

recently I have become annoyed by the number of auxiliary files that are created when I run LaTeX. I have read some threads about this, and I found out a relatively convenient solution for me is to create separate directories with the name of each paper, so that all the files relative to one paper go into that single folder, instead of having all the files from all the documents in the same folder. I hope that was clear. However, since I need to access my .bib file in every paper, it would be convenient for me if this file could reside one directory up from the individual folders, rather than me having to put a copy of the .bib file into every single folder. Currently I cannot find a way to do that.

Potentially relevant information (or not): I preferable use BibLatex on Biber. My editor is Winedt 10.3. I use Jabref to create the .bib files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biber and BibTeX usually accept relative paths, so you can say

```
\addbibresource{../lit.bib}
```

to access a file `lit.bib` one level up from the working directory of your current file.

Note that all paths are interpreted relative to the working directory of the pdfLaTeX/Biber call.

But you could also add the `.bib` file to a path that is automatically searched by BibTeX and Biber, see [Creating a central bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38287/35864).

Comment: Excellent, I specified the path as you said and that worked.