# Telling TeXstudio where to find my .bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, texstudio

I have an issue which I'm sure is familiar to anyone else who uses TeXstudio. If I'm working on some file, say it's called Doc1.tex, and I want to use Bibliography.bib in it, then TeXstudio will look for that Bibliography.bib in whatever folder of my computer has Bibliography.bib in it. So, for example, if Doc1.tex is in Folder 1, then it will look for Bibliography.bib in Folder 1. On the other hand, if I have Doc2.tex in Folder 2, then when Doc2.tex calls on Bibliography.bib, TeXstudio will look for *this* Bibliography.bib in Folder 2.

The way I've been handling this so far is that I have a different copy of Bibliography.bib for every folder I work with. So there's a version in Folder 1, a version in Folder 2, etc. This means that I currently have several different versions of this file, when I'd much rather just have one file that has all the references I might wanna call on, so I don't have to remember if a specific citation I want to use is in the Folder 1 version, or the Folder 2 version, etc.

I'm assuming the simplest way to do this would be to tell TeXstudio to look for Bibliography.bib in one specific place, e.g. in Folder 0, so I can just have the one version of Bibliography.bib in Folder 0. However, I'm pretty intimidated by all the many different menus in TeXstudio, and have no idea where I'd look to find the setting I need. I'd appreciate help with a solution to my issue of many versions of Bibliography.bib.

Thanks!

Postscript: I'm not very familiar with TeX overall, so I apologize if my tags are wrong.

Comment: There are two levels here: For "TeX" to resolve your references correctly it is enough that BibTeX/Biber find your file. This can be done by supplying a relative file path, an absolute path or by putting the file in a directory searched by `kpsewhich` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38287/35864). Additional features like auto-complete of cite commands in the editor are up to TeXstudio. So you probably also need TeXstudio to find the `.bib` file. In my experience this works well with relative and absolute files, but less so with `kpsewhich` files.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question.  Here's how I solved it.  Go to TexStudio's 'Options' menu.  In the options dialogue box, make sure the 'Show Advanced Options' selection box is checked.  Then you should see the 'Adv. Editor' tab in the options list on the left-hand side.  Go to that screen and you will find the 'Additional Search Paths' dialogue, where you can set the path for bibliography files.  Hope this helps.

[image: Adv. Editor Options]